# Animate image to original position after mouse leaves div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The JS script I'm using creates a parallax effect on a few images with mouse hover. After the mouse leaves the hover area, the images remain in the last position until the user re-enters the hover area - this causes the images to snap to the new mouse position.

I've been trying to modify the script to start the images in an origin position, then smoothly animate to the mouse position when it detects a mouse hover, returning again to the origin after leaving. I'm open to any wild solutions, I've also tried leveraging CSS animations to no avail.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.extend({

        mouseParallax: function(options) {

            var defaults = { moveFactor: 5, zIndexValue: "-1", targetContainer: 'body' };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                var background = $(this);

                $(o.targetContainer).on('mousemove', function(e){

                    mouseX = e.pageX;
                    mouseY = e.pageY;

                    windowWidth = $(window).width();
                    windowHeight = $(window).height();

                    percentX = ((mouseX/windowWidth)*o.moveFactor) - (o.moveFactor/2);
                    percentY = ((mouseY/windowHeight)*o.moveFactor) - (o.moveFactor/2);

                    leftString = (0-percentX-o.moveFactor)+"%";
                    rightString = (0-percentX-o.moveFactor)+"%";
                    topString = (0-percentY-o.moveFactor)+"%";
                    bottomString = (0-percentY-o.moveFactor)+"%";

                    background[0].style.left = leftString;
                    background[0].style.right = rightString;
                    background[0].style.top = topString;
                    background[0].style.bottom = bottomString;
                    if(o.zIndexValue) { 
                        background[0].style.zIndex = o.zIndexValue;
                    }
                });
            });
        }                   
    });

  $('#background').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 5 });
    $('#foreground').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 10 });
    $('#fore-foreground').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 15 });
    $('#fore-fore-foreground').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 20 });

    $('body').height(3000);

} (jQuery) );
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zj9djopm/2/

Comment: give the animation a movement vector towards the current mouse position, speeding up at first and slowing down when coming close to the destination. when the mouse leaves the desired area, set the move vector to zero. this will require an increment of the vector per step/frame and a max value for the vector to be capped at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than simply letting them snap into place, try and leverage the .animate property jQuery offers you.

Something like this should work:

```
$(o.targetContainer).on('mouseout', function(e){
  $(background[0]).animate({
    left: "0",
    right: "0",
    top: "0",
    bottom: "0"
  });
});
```

Similarly, for the mouseenter state, you would have to do the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

try to reset position on mouseout event.

```
$(o.targetContainer).on('mouseout', function(e){
    background[0].style.left = 0
    background[0].style.right = 0;
    background[0].style.top = 0;
    background[0].style.bottom = 0;
});
```

[jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/zj9djopm/3/)

hope it will help